# How to create an alias for multiple stream operations?

Tags: c++, c++98

Is there a way to create a shorthand alias for the following line in C++98?

```
std::precision(3) << std::fixed
```

And then use the alias as follows:

```
std::cout << alias << 3.1415926 << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is C++ 99?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The new upcoming 2099 standard.

Comment: Probably just use a `#define`.

Comment: Or `const auto alias = std::precision(3)`

Comment: Or maybe a lambda? But I'm not sure it's available in C++99

Comment: Can't use `auto` or `lambda`. c99: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99

Comment: That standard has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @GillBates As if it will be finished before the turn of the century.

Comment: @GillBates: lol

Comment: @user1054424: Buddy that's a _C_ standard. It's a different language... There is no "C++99".

Comment: sorry - C++98 was what I meant. Corrected in the original post

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard way would probably be to create a custom manipulator:

```
std::ios_base& alias(std::ios_base& str) {
    str.precision(3);
    return std::fixed(str);
}
```

Then:

```
std::cout << alias << 3.16464;
```

See overload (9) of [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&))
```

---

If you want to specify arguments, you need an intermediate structure:

```
struct alias_t {
    int n;
};

alias_t setalias(int n) { return {n}; }

template <class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& out, const alias_t& alias) {
    return out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(alias.n);
}

// Or if you do not care about genericity:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const alias_t& alias) {
    return out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(alias.n);
}
```

Then:

```
std::cout << setalias(6) << 3.16464;
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer those two lines to just `return str << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;`? I mean functionally rather than stylistically.

Comment: @TartanLlama `str` is not a stream here, so this would not work I think.

Comment: @Holt Ah, right. I guess it would work if the function used `std::ostream&` instead, but that wouldn't be as generic?

Comment: @TartanLlama This only works due to the overload I mentioned, but you could achieve similar behavior by creating a custom class with a single instance and overloading `operator <<` for ostream.

Comment: `std::ostream` [already has](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59743147756c5855) the relevant overload. But no matter, your answer is better anyway :)

Comment: @Holt is there a way to have `alias` take an argument so I can set the precision as a function argument? `std::cout << alias(2) << 3.16464` ?

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes you're right - I always forgot this one. The only advantage of the `std::ios_base` in this case is that it is more generic (you could make the yours a bit more generic but it would require a template). I also prefer `std::ios_base` because it is the one used by `std::fixed` and alike manipulator.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 Yes, but it might a bit more complicated, I will update my answer.